# How to Update Vector Count for an Existing Index in Vertex AI?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, embedding, google-cloud-vertex-ai, vertex

I'm working with Google Vertex AI and have an existing index where I need to update the vector count. What is the recommended approach for updating the vector count of an existing index? Is there a way to trigger this update without creating a new index, especially considering the compaction process and its timeline? Any insights or suggestions on managing this process efficiently would be greatly appreciated.

I have encountered this [page](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/vector-search/update-rebuild-index#python) but I'm not sure this updates the vector count or only specific data points.

Basically, I'm creating a network where users can upload images and it creates an embedding into my Google bucket and I want to update my Index with the bucket.

Comment: Seems like what you want is streaming update the vector index. Don't believe that is available for vector count given how the index is structured. One alternative is to store the count as a metadata in storage, then use the API you listed to perform streaming update to update the index metadata. If you need the embedding semantics updated, batch updating might be the path to go.

Comment: The problem is not really just with the count itself, but more with the data that is stored in the storage. Seems like the data is only syncing once (on init) to the index and then when I upload a new embedding I don't see it on my vector search @GangChen

Comment: It wouldn't automatically update the index when the embedding source (GCS bucket) changes. You need to either use REST API or SDK (cli or console) to trigger the update. For batch mode, you need to pass `completeOverwrite=true` as part of the update if you need to get the data updated (not just metadata). Compaction is separate process as part of the update. for batch, if the data change size is smaller than 20%, compaction wouldn't trigger. I feel that your case fitting more into the streaming update situation.

Comment: Thank you @GangChen. I will try to update it directly from the console I guess because I couldn't find the function to update it with my node.js SDK.
Another question is about the charges: i'm getting like 50$ a day for no more than 20 searches with a vector count of 6.. how is that possible?

Comment: Can't address the charge question, please check your billing page for detail about the usage.